# Tapping on hot question in the feed mode is not working

Tags: bug, ios-app

When on feed mode, tapping on any hot question (top line with big blocks) is not working. Nothing happen.

- App Version: 1.6.0.10
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)